# About the NativeActivity in Android 2.2/NDK-r5

Tags: android

With the NDK-r5, we can create Native Activities with C++.
My question is: Can it be run in Android 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the NDK-r5, we can create Native Activity in c++.

No. `NativeActivity` is a class in Android 2.3.

> Can it be run in android 2.2 ?

No. `NativeActivity` is a class introduced in Android 2.3, and therefore does not exist in Android 2.2.