# Can NativeActivity be used on a device running Android 2.2?

Tags: android-ndk

This is a followup to [About the NativeActivity in Android 2.2/NDK-r5。](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838029/about-the-nativeactivity-in-android-2-2-ndk-r5)

The example AndroidManifest.xml with the [NativeActivity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) and `(android_ndk)/samples/native-activity/AndroidManifest.xml` in both R6 and R6b include

```
<!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Attempting to build with `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` in Appliction.mk fails horribly because `(android_ndk)/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/android` is nearly empty.

Despite this being a very silly idea, I tried to build a library with `APP_PLATFORM := android-9` in Application.mk and build a .apk with `target=android-8` in default.properties.  To my surprise, it built.  Not to my surprise, it didn't run.

It seems unlikely, but is there some way to make this work on Android 2.2?

I have filed a bug report with Google since it is most likely a documentation error, but I thought I would raise the issue here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeActivity was introduced in Android 2.3. The sample in the documentation has at least two errors: `minSdkVersion` should be 9 and `android:hasCode` should be `true`.

So NO, you cannot make it working on Android 2.2.